# Adding a user from index doesn't work using CakePhp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, web, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePhp 2.3 and am trying to allow a user to create an account from the home page. I'm new to cakephp and so far I've followed implementation described here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Now every time I access the index page (localhost) I am redirected to the users/login page. I've played around with changing the components array in the AppsController, but if I don't include the Auth component then when I call the function add in the USerController, then I get a *Call to a member function allow() on a non-object* error. I'm not sure how to continue. Right now my AppController class looks like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
'Session',
'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
    'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
)
);


 public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
 }
}
```

**All I want to do** is be able to add a new user row from the index page. Any ideas or other suggested reading? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Configure your home page / by [using the router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration) to use the posts/index action.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Also I guess you're not calling the parent::beforeFilter() in your whatever controller is used for the home page. Allowing actions in the AppController is a bad idea because it just opens security issues. One day you need an index  that should not be public and forget about it OR your have to change all allow() calls.

However, why do you have the login in the posts context? That's wrong. User related actions should belong to the right context: Users controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the key 'authorize', I think you should define the function 'isAuthorized' as described here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

How looks like your default index page ?

If it's the defaut "home.ctp", displayed by the PagesController, you have to allow 'display' as an allowed action :

```
$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view', 'display');
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

go to app->config-> routes.php and change the action to index as @burzum said

and then go to your UsersController or PostsController whatever your controller is call beforeFilter like this

```
 <?php
  class UsersController extends AppController {
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

 }
 public function index(){

 }
```